# Sharepoint 2010 and 'My Sites Blog'

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, feature, my-site

I'm working with a customer to try to help them create a new site with a template they have created.  I am able to reproduce the error locally, which is:
The site template requires that the Feature
{863DA2AC-3873-4930-8498-752886210911} be activated in the site collection.

This is in "My Site", and from googling this seems to refer to a Site Collection Feature called 'My Site Blogs'.  However this feature doesn't seem to exist at the site collection or site level.  I created a blog site from the template for my site, but the error persists.

So I'm definitely confused here... if a Blog is a Site, then what is the feature that is missing called 'My Site Blogs' and how do I activate it?  It seems to me that a template is just of a site- so wouldn't include the blog site anyways, right?

I have full admin access to the farm, site collection and site features- I just don't see any feature with the guid matching above (I looked with view source on the features page).

Anyone?

Comment: This would be better asked on [SharePoint.SE]

Comment: I concur with Kyle -- this isn't even about *programming* in SharePoint (which is a question type I believe *would* be suitable here), but about SharePoint management/customization.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this issue? I am having the same problem. The "My Sites Blog" feature doesn't appear anywhere in the UI. Not at the Site Collection level or the Site level. I may have to crack open the WSP and modify it so it doesn't require that Feature.

Comment: Did my answer below correct this issue for you? If so please mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A blog on a mysite is created using the "My Sites Blog" feature.  It's a site scoped feature, so you should be able to activate it by going to `My Actions > Site Settings > Site Collection Features` and finding the "My Sites Blog" feature.

I don't have a my sites collection handy, so I can't test this for you.

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well- but the feature 'My Sites Blog' doesn't exist there...  I'll take this up on the sharepoint stackexchage as well.  Thanks.

Comment: So now this is on the proper site :) But there is no My Sites Blog feature -anywhere- on my sharepoint site.  Does it need to be enabled somehow?

Answer (score 0):

If you open the Site Template using the Visual Studio project "*Import SharePoint Solution Package*" you can modify it so that those features are not required. This is done by remming out, using , the following features in the **Web Templates | {ProjectName} | ONet.xml** file.

- MySiteBlog Feature
- MySitePersonalSite Feature
- MySiteLayouts Feature

This fixed the issue for me.